# Is $g = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f(\cdot - n)$ continuous if $f$ is vanishing, continuous, and integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, limits-and-convergence, continuity

Let $f \in \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a continuous and integrable function such that $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ when $|x|\rightarrow \infty$.

The sequence of a functions $f_N = \sum_{|n|\leq N} f(\cdot - n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ of integrable and $1$-periodic functions. Indeed, we have that, for $M \geq N \geq 1$,
\begin{equation}
\| f_N - f_M \|_{L^1(\mathbb{T})} = \int_{0}^1 |f_N(x) - f_M(x)|\mathrm{d} x 
\leq \int_{N+1}^{M+1} |f(x)|\mathrm{d}x + \int_{-M}^{-N} |f(x)|\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
which is arbitrarily small for $N,M$ large enough due to the integrability of $f$. Therefore, $f_N$ converges to a function $g = \sum_{n \in\mathbb{Z}} f(\cdot-  n) \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$, which is the periodization of $f$.

**Question:** Can we prove that the function $g$ is continuous? Otherwise, can we construct a counterexample?

Comment: $g$ need not even be everywhere finite - take $f$ which has a peak of width and height $1/n$ at each $n\in\mathbb N$ and is zero elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed, this closes the question. Thank you.